# Divisors of $2^p-n$ where p is a prime.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What do we know about the divisors of $2^p-n$ where $p$ is a prime. I know the form of the divisors if $n=1$ which is a mersenne number.

Comment: I doubt we can really say anything unless possibly when $n$ is a power of $2$.

Comment: @Wojowu I think we can do a little better than that.

Comment: Please elaborate..